# Изменение apk-файла

Tags: apk

Помогите разобраться. Меняю икону в apk-файле и столкнулась с проблемой. Есть два apk-файла одной и той же программы, более старая версия и новая. Меняю через apk editor. Дело в том, что при смене иконы в старой версии программа запускается и исправно работает. И новая программа работает, но после того как поменяла иконку, она так же запускается, но показывает только белый экран и название программы в шапке окна. В чем может быть проблема? И возможна ли какая то защита в новой версии программы?

Answer (score 1):

Нужен ваш код, так смотреть в воду нереально. 
А догадываюсь, что вы просто не закинули в папочки спец. изображения, названия папок на [картинке](http://cs617227.vk.me/v617227935/1c74a/AhR4LGLEmsQ.jpg).

Если хотите просто для красоты на уже установленном приложении, то вам [сюда](http://lifehacker.ru/2014/07/16/izmenit-ikonki-rabochego-stola-android/).

> В приложении можно редактировать и
> заменять на свои различные иконки и
> графические элементы пользовательского
> интерфейса. Для этого открываем папку
> res в папке с декомпилированным
> приложением APK, здесь можно увидеть
> папки:
>
> drawable-hdpi
>
> drawable-ldpi
>
> drawable-mdpi
>
> В данных папках находятся все иконки и
> другие графические элементы программы.
> Буква перед «dpi» означает размер
> графических элементов, соответственно:
>
> hdpi – высокая плотность точек на
> дюйм, размер 72х72 пикселя
>
> mdpi – средняя плотность точек на
> дюйм, размер 48х48 пикселя
>
> ldpi – низкая плотность точек на дюйм,
> размер 36х36 пикселя
>
> Для того, чтобы изменить, например,
> иконку приложения, открываем файл
> AndroidManifest.xml при помощи
> программы Notepad++, ищем строчку, в
> которой указана иконка, смотрим точное
> её название (обратите внимание,
> расширение файла не прописывается,
> только имя файла).
>
> Открываем соответствующую папку
> drawable-*dpi, вставляем
> отредактированную или новую иконку, не
> забываем перепроверить исходное
> название в AndroidManifest.xml.
> Картинка обязательно должна быть в
> формате .png и иметь точно такую же
> плотность точек, как исходный файл,
> например для hdpi это 72х72 пикселя.
>
> Если есть желание заменить название
> иконки на своё, то сохраняем картинку
> с желаемым именем файла в
> drawable-*dpi, после чего указываем
> точно такое же имя в
> AndroidManifest.xml (например
> android:icon=»@drawable/test»). Таким
> же образом можно изменить любые другие
> графические элементы, но требования те
> же – обязательно расширение .png и
> плотность точек на дюйм, как у
> исходного файла.

Resourse: http://fans-android.com/vsyo-ob-apk/

Comment: Это я все понимаю, но ведь в старой версии программы все получается без проблем. И иконки заменяются, и программа работает. А с новой те же самые манипуляции не проходят.

Comment: Просто сделайте так, как написано, я не вижу ни кода, ни иерархии ваших папок.  
Если скинете, то можно что-то говорить.  
А самое главное! При замене картинки она должна быть такого же размена и формата, как и прошлая! И даже название должно быть идентичным!
___

Если помог ставьте +.

Comment: Программа reptilicus. Новая версия на 4pda, старая в поиске должна быть. Только что попробовала сделать, как вы сказали, все так же, открывается, но экран остается белым.

Comment: Тогда мне нужен код вашей программы.

Comment: Сюда скопировать код?
___

Сейчас нет такой возможности, могу ссылку на программу кинуть. Я просто с телефона пока сижу, у компа буду только завтра.
____

http://4pda.ru/pages/go/?u=http%3A%2F%2Freptilicus.net%2Fstore%2Freptilicus.apk

Comment: Буду дома, посмотрю и, может, даже помогу, а я так понял, что вы хотите изменить иконку чужого приложения, верно?

Comment: Верно, буду очень благодарна.

Comment: Нету времени, дома не бываю, когда сяду за комп, обязательно помогу!

Answer (score 1):

Reptilicus. Это стоит защита в самой программе, т.к. имеется такая платная функция в приложении. Просто сверяет хэш или имя, если вы и тут решили схитрить. Я пытался менять и имя и значок, и понял, что тщетно